# Не работает wss соединение в FireFox

Tags: websocket, firefox

Всем привет. Столкнулся с замечательной проблемой, не работает вебсокетное подключение в firefox. На сайте установлен ssl сертификат, протокол https. На сервере также установлен сертификат и подключение идет через wss. В браузерах Chrome, Yandex, Opera всё работает. Один firefox Говорит "Firefox не может установить соединение с сервером wss://хост:порт/"

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://хост:порт/");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542460/secure-websocket-wss-doesnt-work-on-firefox

Comment: Я же не могу сказать пользователям, что им надо сначала зайти на ws1.domain.com, а после этого вернуться обратно